# Render from shaders has no effect

Tags: ios, opengl-es

This **does not render anything** apart from the cleared color:

```
  glUseProgram(_rectificationShader.program);

  // do other things like assigning attributes

  glGenFramebuffers(1, &_internalFramebuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _internalFramebuffer);

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glGenTextures(1, &_referenceTexture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _referenceTexture);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_EXT, referenceImage.cols, referenceImage.rows, 0, GL_RED_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, referenceImageData);
  GLKMatrix3 homography1 = [Utility cvHomographyToOpenGL:H1];
  glUniformMatrix4fv(_rectificationShader.rectificationMatrix, 1, 0, homography1.m);
  glUniform1i(_rectificationShader.tex, GL_TEXTURE0);

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
  glGenTextures(1, &_referenceRectifiedTexture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _referenceRectifiedTexture);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_EXT, width, height, 0, GL_RED_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _referenceRectifiedTexture, 0);
  GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

  if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
    return NO;
  }

  glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, imageArea);
```

The shaders (simplified for debugging):

```
// Vertex Shader

static const char* rectificationVS = STRINGIFY
(
 attribute highp vec2 position;
 varying highp vec2 texCoords;

 void main(void)
 {
   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
   texCoords = position.xy * vec2(0.5) + vec2(0.5);
 }

 );

// Fragment Shader

static const char* rectificationFS = STRINGIFY
(
 varying highp vec2 texCoords;
 uniform lowp sampler2D tex;

 void main(void)
 {
   gl_FragColor = vec4(1);
 }

 );
```

Positions are fed in to the vertex shader and go from (-1,-1) to (1,1). Is there anything I am missing? If I change the clear color, I can see the change in my exported image (code omitted).

Comment: Are you missing the viewport?

Comment: That was it! What a beginner error. Now I cannot get values from the input texture, but that's another question...

Comment: Are you sure when setting the texture uniform you shouldnt set 0 instead of GL_TEXTURE0?

Comment: Correct! I now can see something, but it doesn't make much sense. If I pass the 4 corners of the image as vertices, will the shader interpolate in the middle? Or do I have to apply my transformation with an input of all of the 640x480 pixels scaled to -1,1?

Comment: The texture coordinates go from 0 to 1 where top left part is at (0,0) and bottom right is at (1,1). The interpolation is done automaticaly by using varying keyword in shaders so that should be all. To test the trxture coordinates in your case it is best to modify the fragment shader to output the color directly from the texture coordinate, for instance use X coordinate for red and Y for blue. The result must be a nice 2D gradient between black, red, blue and red-blue color..

Comment: I have a b/w image and red channel-only texture, so I tested with a gradient based on coords that goes between black and white: `gl_FragColor = vec4(texCoords, 0, 1);` What I get though is a lot of small rectangles, I can see the gradient inside them, but it's not one big rectangle that covers the whole viewport.

Comment: This is my current output: http://postimg.org/image/m8e21umhf/

Comment: How did you get that image, from pixel buffer or presenting the buffer on the screen? This seems a bit larger issue then missplaced texture coordinates..

Comment: I use `glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rawImagePixels);` to then feed into an OpenCV Mat and finally save it into the photo album of the device.

Comment: Yes that is the issue as the width and height must be the same as in buffer. And in buffer you put referenceImage.cols...

Comment: I just put the same dimensions everywhere and triple checked, but the result is *thinner* rectangles...

Comment: There are now two large parts of your application that are potencial of creating the issue. To rule out the one on how you are creating the image could you try drawing this texture to some presentable buffer: After you draw this image get the screen buffer and bind it, bind the _referenceTexture, set the viewport and draw the same rectangle.. See if you can get a correct result this way because I see no way to get the result you got just with the drawing.

Comment: Actualy it kind of looks like you are getting a single byte per pixel image from the (the red one) but when you create the image with CV it expects a whole 3byte RGB pixel buffer. Thus the image seems to be divided into 3 columns as a single image row actually contains 3 texture rows.

Comment: You were right again, it was the saving code. I rewrote it in pure Cocoa, and now I can see a nice, full image gradient, black (left) to white (right). Will start working on the shaders to do what I wanted to do, finally. Thanks a ton!